# Eclipse Plugin For: Creating, Connecting And Insert A SQL Database Into A Java Application

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, sqlite, jdbc

Is there a plugin for eclipse that allows the user to create, connect and insert a SQL database into an application, all from within eclipse?

I'm new to working with databases, while I understand the syntax of SQL well enough to write the code, I find working with external SQL software(MySQL and SQLite), then importing files into my application to be a little overwhelming at this point.  Additionally, tutorials online seem varied, and multistage in such a way that I find it difficult to find "the right approach".

I'm sure this is something I will become familiar with in time, but for now I'd really like to just experiment by building simple applications that utilize a database.

I was hoping to streamline this process by finding a plugin that could handle most of the above for me.  Preferably with heavy use of a GUI.  Recommendations?

If such a plugin doesn't exist, or if you have other related suggestion about: software, tutorials, or advice on the simplest way to incorporate a database into my work, I'd like to hear that too.

Two finial questions. One, I've worked with MySQL and SQLite.  Can/would you recommend alternative software for working with a Java application?  Two, do I need to DL and install JDBC software or is that included in the JDK 8?

I'm currently running Windows 8.1 and eclipse Luna.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look for following plugin:

1. [Eclipse SQL Explorer](http://eclipsesql.sourceforge.net/)
2. [Eclipse Data Tools Platform (DTP) Project](https://eclipse.org/datatools/)